# How does heap-spray attack work?

Tags: c++, c, security, exploit

I've read two articles about heap-spraying: [Wikiepdia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_spraying) and [this blog post](http://sf-freedom.blogspot.com/2006/06/heap-spraying-introduction.html).
I understand how the shell code is introduced in to the program's memory. But how the program is made to jump/call to the address memory located on heap?

What kind of crash makes a call to heap?

Does such attack needs to be conducted with a kind of buffer overflow attack?

Is there any golden rule like the one with buffer overflow ie use the n version of functions (`strncpy` instead `strcpy`)?

Comment: See http://www.darkreading.com/vulnerabilities---threats/heap-spraying-attackers-latest-weapon-of-choice/d/d-id/1132487 and https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2011/12/31/exploit-writing-tutorial-part-11-heap-spraying-demystified/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly,

> They commonly take advantage from the
>   fact that these heap blocks will
>   roughly be in the same location every
>   time the heap spray is run. Execution
>   flow can be redirected to the heap
>   sprays via buffer overflow or heap
>   overflow flaws.

They're talking about a situation like this:

```
char buffer[10];
FuncPtr p;
```

And when you read into `buffer` there's no overflow protection, and you can write directly into the memory location for `p`. Later on when your code tries to call `p`, it will jump to where the attacker wants it to jump, presumably where they injected executable code into your app.

Simple fix: Don't use static buffers (prefer the `std::` collection classes) and always check for overflows.

Comment: It seams I've missed that sentence on the wikipedia :) Thanks!